# EdgeType.DIRECTED not working

Tags: java, eclipse, graph, jung

I recently figured out how to add the Jung libraries to eclipse, but now I ran into a new problem. I'm using the  [Jung tutorial](http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf) and I can't seem to run the first tutorial, because the Eclipse IDE is saying that the .DIRECTED ,in the code, cannot be resolved or is not a field. How do I fix this?

edit: Yes, using that package worked! However, I'm surprised that the Eclipse IDE did not offer to import the package for me. Is this unusual?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include all the required JUNG2 libraries into your Eclipse project. When you do that, Eclipse will give a few suggestions after you right-click on those yellow-underlined words. Choose the one(s) related to JUNG2 to remove the warning(s).

`EgeType.DIRECTED` must be imported from `edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType` package which is under `jung-graph-impl-2.0.1.jar`